# How to read and write large number (~1 Million ) of entities of a model in GAE Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to read and write large number (~1 Million ) of entities of a model in GAE Python ?

My ndb Model :

```
class X (ndb.Model): 
    Y = ndb.JsonProperty ( "a", repeated=True, indexed=False ) 
    # max list length = 10. 
    # Example of a list stored in Y above : 
    # Y = [ 
    #       { "n" : "name_p__of_around_100_chars", "s" : number_p__between_0_and_100, "a" : "address_p__of_200_chars" }, 
    #       { "n" : "name_q__of_around_100_chars", "s" : number_q__between_0_and_100, "a" : "address_q__of_200_chars" }, 
    # ]
```

I need to read entities of model `"X"` and update its property `"Y"` and write is back to NDB.

**My First Approach**
Read all entities using `ndb.get_multi ( key_list )`.
This approach failed because it hit memory limit issue at `ndb.get_multi ()`:

> Exceeded soft private memory limit of 512 MB with 623 MB after
>   servicing 1 requests total

Has anybody done this earlier ?
What is the best way to do it ?

I am doing this inside a `TaskQueue Push` queue to avoid any request timeouts.

**WHAT SOLVED MY PROBLEM**
Thanks everyone. I optimised my algorithm ( which was too messy earlier ) and got rid of the memory issue. All of your suggestions were very informative but the real problem was my bad algo. So i am not in a position to mark any answer as accepted here.

I am leaving this question here ( not deleting it even though it was a problem with my code ) so that somebody else could get good pointers in memory leak issue on GAE Python.

Thanks Dmitry Sadovnychyi, Dan Cornilescu and Tim Hoffman.

Comment: Use mapreduce, or .fetch_page with precessing limited batch in a single request and creating new task with next cursor after.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi Thanks. I would try it but GAE does not release memory after reading the entities for quite some time. I read sets of entities ( say 100 ) using `fetch_page`, and fire `TaskQueue` task for that set of 100 entities. When I read the next set of 100 entities, the memory ( RAM ) for the earlier set of 100 entities would still remain. New memory would become 100 + 100 = 200.

Comment: You could try calling gc.collect

Comment: Never had such problems with memory, try to use smaller batches, iterations or gc.collect as suggested.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I optimised my algorithm ( which was too messy earlier ) and got rid of the memory issue. All of your suggestions were very informative but the real problem was my bad algo. So i am not in a position to mark any answer as accepted here. Thanks Dmitry Sadovnychyi, Dan Cornilescu and Tim Hoffman.

Answer (score 1):

You could split your **key_list** in smaller pieces and iterate through them.

Watch out as TaskQueue also has a time quota, so you're not avoiding just "any timeout", you may need to further split the overall iteration into smaller chunks.

I'm thinking this could make good use of the Pipeline API to address scalability - you might want to take a look at this article: https://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/19/the-google-app-engine-pipeline-api